Leaflet : how to force using a specific tile server when zooming on known locations?
I'm using leaflet for displaying some maps.
I know that my users will zoom in for some location.
As you know, tiles are realtime calculated if zoom is high.
I want to store pre calculated zoomed tiles on my server only for some location (the ones my users will likely zoom in) : this will speed up my leaflet page and this will avoid calculation on the global tiles server.
Does anyone know how this can be done ?
I know the leaflet subdomains option exists ( https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer ), but it does not work the way I need.
I'd like leaflet to search on my server only for some x(min/max),y(min/max),z(min/max) parameters, or at least that leaflet search on my server before, and fallback to the other server only in case of 404...
Thanks

What if you wrote your server so that if you request a tile that has not been cached you serve back the one from the official source? That way the client does not have to be aware at all of the logic behind the tiles being served to them?

Indeed, that is a different approach, but this would reach the expected result.
And by the way, I would really master which tiles I want to store locally ...
But that needs a bit of programming, I'll think about it
Thanks
